# BeautifulSoup detect NoFollow

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml, python-requests

I am looking for BeautifulSoup to detect NoFollow/DoFollow in a link. Is there an easy way to do this? I am looking for an option that will ignore case sensitivity and work with different ways rel=nofollow is placed.

I have this but it does not work:

```
        if 'nofollow' in link:
            print "Nofollow"
        else:
            print "Dofollow"
```

Edit: Actually I figured it out, here is code:

```
        if link in soup.find_all(rel="nofollow"):
            print "NoFollow"
        else:
            print "Dofollow"
```

Seems like it is working, I will test it more and edit if there is need for exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

```
links = soup.find_all(rel=True)  # This will find all links which has an attribute named 'rel'
for link in links:
    print link['rel']   # This will print the value of rel attribute while looping through the earlier found links
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, but when I do this:
          `if soup.findAll(attrs={'rel': re.compile("nofollow", re.I)}):
            print "Nofollow"`
It prints all the links NoFollow. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: I just edited the answer to meet your specific needs. Hope that helps.

Comment: rather than making inline comments which need scrolling you can write a short explanation

Comment: Thanks @UmNyobe for your valuable feedback. I will definitely take care of this from now on.

Comment: Hi, I have tried to modify it to read nofollow status, but to no avail. Sorry for making this difficult, but it works only with rel, it cant detect nofollow.
I have tried multiple times and read a lot of documentation but still it wont work, here is my code:
`links = soup.find(rel=True)
        if link['rel="nofollow"'] in links:
            print link['rel']`
It is important for me to correctly detect nofollow so my scraper wont follow them and abuse someones website and rules...